# Viewflow - Modify how Process URL appear?

Tags: django-viewflow

Is it possible to configure Viewflow such that the Process Summary and Process URL display something more useful (such as `process.website.name`?)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdzJO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort; that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can provide the frontend and process specific views.

To customize process specific view you could register custom viewset with `frontend.register(HelloWorldFlow, HelloWorldViewSet)`

To provide custom fontend view, you can create own frontend app, with customized viewset

```
from viewflow.frontend.viewset import FrontendViewSet as BaseFrontendViewSet
from viewflow.frontend.viewset import FrontendViewSet as BaseFrontendViewSet
from viewflow.frontend.views import AllTaskListView as BaseAllTaskListView

class FrontendViewSet(BaseFrontendViewSet):
    inbox_view_class = views.AllTaskListView



class FrontendViewSet(BaseFrontendViewSet):
    inbox_view_class = MyTaskListView


class MyTaskListView(BaseAllTaskListView):
    list_display = [
        'task_hash', 'description'
    ]
```

Or simply, you can provide custom process summary template to put required information into existing summary column - https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/helloworld/flows.py#L25